# Content being cropped when scaling a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a div that can be zoomed in on using the 'scale' property. However, when I scale up an image, it scales fine, however the outsides of the image are being cropped and I can't scroll around the page to see the rest of the image for some reason.

Example on codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLGFl

So if you look at Greenland for example, and then you click the 'in' button, you'll see after the image has been scaled, 90% of Greenland disappears and you cannot scroll back up to view the missing part of Greenland or anywhere else on the map, which is what I want to be able to do.

I've tried things like adding `background-size:cover and 100% 100%`, I've tried adding `overflow:auto`, I've tried putting the image in an image tag within the `map-container` div and I've tried putting another div around the `map-container` div that has a fixed width and height with `overflow:auto` on it but I'm getting the same results every time.

Any help with this is much appreciated!

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION:**

To fix it, I used Candlejack's solution and change my `zoomIn()` function by setting a variable to change the top/left position depending on how far it was zoomed in. I had to do trial/error to get the right values for my site. I also had to use the same code below (with zoomMargin changes in the switch statement) in my `zoomOut()` function to change back to the previous `zoomMargin` value.

```
var zoomMargin = 0;
function zoomIn(){
    //get the id of the element to be scaled and scale it using GSAP
    var mapContainer = document.getElementById("map-container");
    TweenMax.set(mapContainer,{transformOrigin: "50% 50%"});
    TweenMax.to(mapContainer, 0.4, { scale: "+=1"});
    console.log("scale: "+mapContainer._gsTransform.scaleX);
    //switch between the scale value (the scale value in my switch statement is from the GSAP library)
    switch(mapContainer._gsTransform.scaleX){
        case 1:
            zoomMargin = 24.9;
        break;
        case 2:
            zoomMargin = 33.3;
        break;
        case 3:
            zoomMargin = 37.5;
        break;
        case 4:
            zoomMargin = 39.9;
        break;
        case 5:
            zoomMargin = 41.6;
        break;
    }
    $('#map-inner-container').css( "top", zoomMargin+"%" );
    $('#map-inner-container').css( "left", zoomMargin+"%" );
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="map-container">
    <div id="map-inner-container">
        <img src="map-url.png" style="z-index:-9999;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the background image out of your `#map-container` and placed it in the markup as an `img` - [as shown here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rGjwo).

This allows scrolling to the full extent of the image, regardless of zoomed level.

You may need to tweak the image styling to resemble your original design, but this should at least solve the immediate scrolling issue.

**EDIT:**

New version here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eHDmG

Added `position: relative` to the img CSS, and then altered the `top` rule in the JS functions for zoomIn/zoomOut.

So far I've used static values of 20% and 0% to demonstrate the point - it only really looks good the first time you zoom in. Ideally these values should be set dynamically depending on which zoom depth you are at. You could set a variable to store an integer which increments every time the user zooms in and decrements every time the user zooms out, and then calculate an appropriate `top` position value depending on this variable.

Comment: I've had a look at your example, but unfortunately, when you zoom in it is still cropping the rest of the image. For example, if you look at Greenland in your link, then click the 'in' button, you'll see the top half of Greenland disappears.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, got it fixed finally using your solution to set the top rule, although I added left as well to keep that from messing up. Added some code in my question edit